# Sublime Text 3: How remove whole line in 1 file that contain a word in 2nd file

Tags: sublimetext3

I have 2 files
File A: contains list of emails
File B: contains list of keywords
I want Sublime to take each keyword in File B and search in File A, then remove all lines that contain that keyword
Please help!

How to use Sublime text to search & replace in 2 files